# Having trouble following a professor's solution

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

We had a homework problem that I was unable to fully solve. The problem is:

If f is measurable on E, define $ω_{f}$(a) = |{f > a}| for −∞ < a < +∞. If
f$_{k}$ increases to f, show that ω$_{f_{k}}$ increases to ω$_{f}$. If f$_{k}$
→ f in measure, show that ω$_{f_{k}}$
→ ω$_{f}$ at each point of continuity of ω$_{f}$.

The first part was easy, but I was unable to show the second part. He sent us a pdf of another professor's solutions, but I'm having trouble following the solution and would appreciate some insight. The solution for the second part is:
[image]

I don't see why |E$_{k}$| < $\eta$. Also, I follow the inequalities after that point, but I don't understand what they're trying to show. Can someone help me out here?

My idea is as follows: since $f_{k}$ converges to f, and so the measure of E$_{k}$ becomes small. Hence, we may use the archimedean property of the reals so that this is true. Then after that point, I follow the inequalities, but I'm unsure of what we're proving. How does this work show that w$_{f_{k}}$ converge to w$_{f}$ at each point of continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part has the assumption that $f_{k}\rightarrow f$ in measure, which means that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|\{x: |f_{k}(x)-f(x)|>\delta\}|=0$ for each fixed $\delta>0$.

Comment: Ah, okay I was being dumb, thank you that clears up why we can have the measure of E$_{k}$ be less than eta. What is being proved after that?

Comment: So $a$ is fixed, the continuity point of $\omega_{f}$. And one should write $\omega_{f_{k}}(a)\leq\eta+\omega_{f}(a-\delta)$ and that $\omega_{f_{k}}(a)\geq\omega_{f}(a+\delta)-\eta$. So it will end up with $-2\eta+\omega_{f}(a)<\omega_{f_{k}}(a)<2\eta+\omega_{f}(a)$.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I'm sorry I was slow to catch on. Thank you this was very helpful.